# Why is the derivative of $\frac{3e^{2x}}{2}$ equal to $3e^{2x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{3e^{2x}}{2}$$

$$f'(x) = 3e^{2x}$$

Why is this true?

Comment: do you know the chain rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x) = e^x$ has the derivative $f'(x) = e^x$.

Recall the **chain rule**:

Let $F(x) = f(g(x))$, then $F'(x) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

This derivative is an application of the chain rule:

Let $F(x) = \frac{3}{2}e^{2x}$. In this case, take $f(x) = \frac{3}{2}e^x, g(x) = 2x$

Then $F(x) = f(g(x))$

Then, by the chain rule, $F'(x) = \frac{3}{2}e^{2x}\cdot 2 = 3e^{2x}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
y & = e^{2x} \\[10pt]
y & = e^u & u & = 2x \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{du} & = e^u & \frac{du}{dx} & = 2 \\[10pt]
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot\frac{du}{dx} \\[10pt]
& = e^u \cdot 2 = e^{2x}\cdot 2
\end{align}